# mootools group checkbox return values

Tags: class, checkbox, mootools, css-selectors, each

How can I return selected checkboxes values from mootools class:

Mootools class:

```
var CheckboxGroup = new Class({

    Implements: Events,

    initialize: function(master, slaves) {
        this.master = $(master);
        this.slaves = $$(slaves);
        this.selected = [];            
        var that = this;

        this.master.addEvent('click', this.onMasterClick.bind(this));
        this.slaves.addEvent('click', function() {
            that.onSlaveClick(this);
        });
    },

    onMasterClick: function() {
        this.slaves.set('checked', this.master.get('checked')).fireEvent('change');
        this.fireEvent('masterClick');
        this.fireEvent('onCheckboxClick');
    },

    onSlaveClick: function(slave) {
        this.master.set('checked', this.slaves.every(function(el) { return el.get('checked'); }));
        this.fireEvent('slaveClick', slave);
        this.fireEvent('onCheckboxClick');
    },

    onCheckboxClick: function() {

    ??? how to return selected values   
    }

});
```

HTML AND SCRIPT:

```
<div class="container">
    <label class="master"><input type="checkbox" id="master" /> Master</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="slave" value="1"/> Slave #1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="slave" value="2"/> Slave #2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="slave" value="3"/> Slave #3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="slave" value="4"/> Slave #4</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="slave" value="5"/> Slave #5</label>
</div>
<script>
        new CheckboxGroup('master', '.slave').addEvents({
        'onCheckboxClick': function() {
            console.log(this.selected); /*EVERY TIME [] ?????*/
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [Selector: checked](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Slick/Slick#Slick%3achecked)
Since it's very easy to get checked element from within a container that contains them I changed your class by adding container element to the constructor(in your example just add id="container" to the container but you can choose how you want to achieve that in your way - this is just for example).

One more thing is you don't need to defined "onCheckboxClick" in your class since this is event you are raising by exposing your API: http://jsfiddle.net/BqVtL/

```
var CheckboxGroup = new Class({

    Implements: Events,

    initialize: function(container,master, slaves) {
        this.container = document.id(container);
        this.master = $(master);
        this.slaves = $$(slaves);
        this.selected = [];            
        var that = this;

        this.master.addEvent('click', this.onMasterClick.bind(this));
        this.slaves.addEvent('click', function() {
            that.onSlaveClick(this);
        });
    },

    onMasterClick: function() {
        this.slaves.set('checked', this.master.get('checked')).fireEvent('change');
        this.setSelected();
        this.fireEvent('masterClick');
        this.fireEvent('onCheckboxClick');
    },

    onSlaveClick: function(slave) {
        this.master.set('checked', this.slaves.every(function(el) { return el.get('checked'); }));
        this.setSelected();
        this.fireEvent('slaveClick', slave);
        this.fireEvent('onCheckboxClick');
    },

    setSelected: function(){
        //you can loose the container mechanism and use $$('.slave:checked').get('value') 
   //     this.selected = this.container.getElements('.slave:checked').get('value');


          //Dimitar Christoff better solution: (then there is no need in container at all)
          this.selected = this.slaves.filter(':checked').get('value');


    }

});

new CheckboxGroup('container','master', '.slave').addEvents({
    'onCheckboxClick': function() {
        console.log(this.selected); /*EVERY TIME [] ?????*/
    }
});
```

Comment: `this.slaves.filter()` would be better as they are cached. in fact, storing them in memory as you loop through them onchange all the time means the whole `setSelected` method can be deprecated. `this.slaves.set('checked', this.master.get('checked')).fireEvent('change');` does 2 consecutive `.each`, BAD - can be used instead to store the selected values. and doing a manual `.fireEvent('change')` through dom element is pointless. anyway, @Adidi - I know it's not your code, this is for the OP.

Comment: nice comment. I agree with you in those aspects and i saw it myself in his Class but I guess he just trying to understand how mootools oop works so in the term of his learning curve I didn't want to mess his head too much... but thanks - your remarks are always insightful :))

Comment: sure - glad somebody is helping out instead of me now. oh yes, 2 consecutive `.each` on slaves and does a new `master.get('checked');` for each one instead of caching the immutable value. I have nearly developed OCD - seeing non-optimised code makes me uncomfortable :)

Comment: hehe - I guess this is how things are with pros like you. in my opinion you have to understand that computers nowdays are not the "main frame" methods of the 80's - with all the javascript improvements and optimization, I don't think the developer (especially in the web-javascript world) have to be worry on every single extra loop if the price of it will be not understanding how the important stuff of his program suppose to work. and I am happy to help you (and mootools) out. I have learned a lot !! from your code hehe and I hope to continue and be more valuable as time come... :))